# How to omit string NA values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, na

I would like to omit all NA values in my a subset of data. However, since all elements of the columns are strings, I cannot use the function na.omit.

Thanks in advance!

```
df <- data_financial_market
financial_assets_separate <- colnames(df)
useful_assets <- df[,endsWith(financial_assets_separate, ".Open.Return")]
index <- df$Index


print(useful_assets$FCHI.Open.Return)

X1 <- na.omit(useful_assets$FCHI.Open.Return)
X2 = useful_assets$DJI.Open.Return
Z = useful_assets$IXIC.Open.Return
```

See for the output: [image: 1]

Comment: Both answers give an error

Comment: Na_if gives: Registered S3 method overwritten by 'cli':
  method     from
  print.tree tree
# A tibble: 10,021 x 13
   FCHI.Open.Return DJI.Open.Return IXIC.Open.Return EURUSD.X.Open.R~ BTC.EUR.Open.Re~ N225.Open.Return FVX.Open.Return
   
We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?

Comment: Df[df =="NA"] tells Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @Jacob what about `useful_assets$FCHI.Open.Return[useful_assets$FCHI.Open.Return == "NA"] <- NA`

Comment: `useful_assets[useful_assets$FCHI.Open.Return != "NA",]`